# Custom 'compile' directive renders ng-repeat multiply times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a custom "compile" directive to render HTML snippets that I push into a div container which is working great. One problem I am having is that it seems like the compile directive gets called multiple times (3x). How can I watch out that it only runs once?

Here is the compile directive:

```
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
            element.html(value);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
};
}]);
```

Then this creates three buttons for every player in Players after the code get loaded into a div.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 mainpage-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-click="changePlane(1)" data-planeOrigin="1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                        <span>Overview</span>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-click="changePlane(2)" data-planeOrigin="2">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        <span>Players</span>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-click="changePlane(3)" data-planeOrigin="3">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>
                        <span>Teams</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 mainpage-main" compile="mainPlane">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
    Overview
-->
<div data-plane="1" class="hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-group">
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="player in players">{{ player.user_name }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
$scope.changePlane = function(planeID) {
    $('[data-planeOrigin="'+currentPlane+'"]').removeClass("active");
    currentPlane = planeID;
    $('[data-planeOrigin="'+planeID+'"]').addClass("active");

    var data = $('[data-plane='+planeID+']').html();
        $scope.mainPlane = data;
};
```

Comment: Where is the `compile` directive in the html?

Comment: Inside the main template for the page in the ng-view.

Comment: Can you update the code as well to look at what is the issue?

Comment: Again, may I know where is the element with the attribute `data-plane` ?

Comment: I want to answer but I'm not sure what you are looking for. All these things are happening in the same Controller and Template.

Comment: If you can provide all the required html, we can able to investigate the issue. The information you gave is not enough to investigate at the moment

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: It looks better now, but I guess you posted a `ng-repeat` previously as per the subject line which I cant see any more, Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130089/discussion-between-jason-and-aruna).

Comment: Otherwise can you explain what you do with the buttons, what expected but what is actually happening?

Comment: At the moment players consists of three elements. When the code runs every one of the 3 elements is shown 3x in a row. So ng-repeat turns 3 Elements into 9